Import Autodesk viewer as a package
I am wondering why I have to include: <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script> in my index.html if I want to use the default Autodesk viewer. Is there a feature complete alternative to this viewer that is imported as a package?

When you look at the licensing information at the top of the viewer3D.min.js file, it states the following:

The Autodesk Viewer SDK JavaScript must be delivered from an Autodesk-hosted URL.

Because of this, it is not possible for us to provide the viewer as an NPM package. The viewer library must always be loaded using a <script> tag.
